# Find number of occurrences of digits from 1 to N without using loop

Tags: java, math, number-theory, induction

For example, n=11 means, then the map should have **0-1, 1-4, 2-1, 3-1, 4-1, 5-1, 6-1, 7-1, 8-1, 9-1**

```
 public void countDigits(int n, Map map) {
          while (n != 0) {
            int d = n%10;
            n /= 10;
            map.put(d,map.get(d)++);
          }
          return result;
        }
```

Other than the above method.
I want to get all the digit count from 1 to N.

Comment: I don't think your loop is doing what you want it to do.. Are you calling it from some other loop iterating from 1 to n?

Comment: Your problem is poorly specified. Please clarify your question.

Comment: what's the logic behind your expected output? please explain.

Comment: There is an easy way to do this with recursion. Write f(10a+b) as a function of f(a), b, and countDigits(a).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Douglas Zare Can you please explain your answer.

Comment: Actually, with these definitions, it's a little simpler to relate f(10a+b) to f(a-1), b, and countDigits(a). Suppose you know the digits which occur in the numbers up to 56. Take the numbers up to 573 and break them into the numbers from 1 through 9, from 10 through 569, and from 570 through 573. Express the digits in one of these sets in terms of the digits of numbers from 1 through 56.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't compiles at all. Try replace `map.put(d,map.get(d)++);` with

```
Integer tmp = (Integer)map.get(d);
if(tmp == null) tmp = 0;
tmp++;
map.put(d,tmp);
```

Comment: It's not an exact code. Just a skeleton which is not need.